# What does "a tremendous flapping and snapping of the four-cylinder engine" mean?

Tags: meaning

I am unsure about the meaning of especially "flapping" but also "snapping" in this 1904 text:

> "It was my privilege, on the 20th day of September, 1904 to see the first successful trip of an airship, without a balloon to sustain it, that the world has ever made, that is, to turn the corners and come back to the starting-point....
>
> The engine is started and got up to speed. The machine is held until ready to start by a sort of trap to be sprung when all is ready; **then with a tremendous flapping and snapping of the four-cylinder engine**, the huge machine springs aloft.
>
> When it first turned that circle, and came near the starting-point, I was right in front of it; and I said then, and believe still, it was one of the grandest sights, if not the grandest sight of my life."

A. I Root, eye witness.

Comment: Did you try to look up "flap" and "snap" in the dictionary? http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flap and http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/snap.

Comment: Yes, but all the meaning I have found for "flap" (see: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flap ) do not seem to apply to a working internal combustion engine.

Comment: When you ask a question, you need to show us your research, what you understand and what you don't. Please read [the link](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) which says: Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: Flap means: the movement or sound of something that is moving up and down or back and forth

Comment: To flap = to move (wings or arms, for example) up and down. How can an engine flap?

Comment: It may be interesting to note that previously in the text the plane is compared with a bird several times: *"a little more push from behind, and the bird or the butterfly, or the machine created by human hands, will gradually rise in the air".* Flap is commonly used to describe the movements of a bird. It may be an extended metaphor.

Comment: Imagine cylinders are moving up and down as if they were birds' wings.

Comment: The pistons of an internal combustion engine can not be seen flapping because they are hidden.

Comment: @RobertWerner It means sound of something that is moving up and down regardless of whether they are hidden or not. You use to flap for human's lips. Can you flap your lip? It is just metaphor as Yay mentioned.

Comment: This is obviously figurative, so looking in a dictionary will not help.

Comment: @RobertWerner - Let me assure you that the back ends of the pistons were quite visible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't think anyone now alive on this site knows how a 1904 airplane engine sounded, and why it sounded as it did.  Try http://aviation.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A 1904 airplane engine sounded like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsPB-0QPLDI

Answer (score 2):

In the early days of internal combustion engines, tolerances and manufacturing quality were nowhere near the levels you see in modern engines, so pistons would literally clatter and slap inside the bore of the engine, irregular firing would mean the engine block would vibrate in its mounting, and the linkages to the valves would clatter as they opened and closed.

Overall, engines from that period were wonderfully noisy, irregular and vibrated intensely, so the author is trying to describe this cacophony.

Comment: Though the juxtaposition of 'wonderful', 'irregular firing', 'flapping, 'snapping' and 'airship' might not have been appreciated by the people in the thing.

Comment: Spot on. At many fairs in the U.S., you can still find such engines; they are sometimes used to make ice cream. [Here's some good audio on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r38g3Ssf70I). Can you imagine the sound of an engine like that, if it was powerful enough to get an airplane into the air?

Comment: @J.R. So, before fridges, they had to go up in an aeroplane to freeze the stuff?

Answer (score 2):

A (hand-made) aircraft engine of that era would have had all of the valve rods and cams and such on the outside, plus even the carburetor may have been a style with a flapping plate or some such.  The piston rod at the back end of the piston would have been exposed, as would have been the crankshaft.  The engine likely would have sputtered irregularly, especially when idling.  The valves would have a definite "snap" as they opened and closed.  (I once owned an old "stationary" farm engine which had valves that were presumably similar, and they made a remarkable clatter as the engine idled.)  The fact that the engine was very lightly built would have made the noise even more intense.

The aircraft itself was little more than a kite, canvas and sticks of wood, held together with ropes and cables.  Especially with the vibration of the engine it would have rattled and flapped as well.

The writer's description may not be technically precise, but no doubt captures the visual and aural cacophony that he observed.

Comment: linky https://airandspace.si.edu/exhibitions/wright-brothers/online/fly/1903/engine.cfm. No carb at all, btw. No throttle or plugs, either. The camshaft opened and closed breaker points in the cylinder for spark.

Comment: 1) Hot Licks, your explanation: "no doubt captures the visual and aural cacophony that he observed" was already given by Rory Alsop: "so the author is trying to describe this cacophony". 2) Excepting the fact it was made partly of aluminium the Wright's motor was just an ordinary engine of the time, similar to what the witness A. I. Root had in his car.

Comment: @PhilSweet - Yeah, I probably should have put "carb" in quotes -- it likely was a reed valve or some such that squirted fuel into the intake manifold rather randomly.  The engine I had was originally equipped with a reed valve, but a prior owner had replaced that with what was claimed to be a Model T carb.  The engine did have the original moving "points" inside the cylinder, though, operated off the camshaft.

Comment: @RobertWerner - I guess since Rory and I independently chose the word "cacophony", it must be a fairly appropriate term.

Comment: I guess that you may be one and the same person with multiple identities.